# Color the area defined by Items intersection in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, overlap, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have some custom `QGraphicsItems` in a `QGraphicsView` of a `QGraphicsScene`. With `items(QPoint(x, y))` method I retrieve all the items at given scene point.
Once these items are drawn they will not be moved, rotated or scaled, so their shapes will not change.

I would to know if there is a way to change the color of the overlapping area only (if I have at least two items, of course).

A different way to write my question is: given a starting  point, color the scene until some borders are found.
I have not enough reputation to post an image, so I uploaded three examples of desired results [here](http://i58.tinypic.com/c1czt.jpg).

**Edit 1:** solution from Nejat works if I select a point that actually is within two Items' shapes, but it doesn't work if the point belongs to only one Item or to no Items (I uploaded an example of this case [here](http://i62.tinypic.com/scc9a8.jpg)).

Maybe should I use a different approach? Once painted, I don't need to change an item, so I will be interested also in a "flat/static" pixel-oriented solution. Could I use `QImage` class?

**Edit 2:** Nejat's answer was right for the original question. Btw, for my purpose I used a `QImage`, drawing on it all the shapes and finally using a "flood fill" algorithm to fill the area I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `QGraphicsItem::shape` () which returns a `QPainterPath` to retrieve the shape of an item. For taking the intersection path this can be used :

```
QPainterPath QPainterPath::intersected ( const QPainterPath & p ) const;
```

So you can get the intersection path of two items like:

```
QPainterPath intersectedPath = item1->shape()->intersected(item2->shape());
```

Now you can fill the intersected area by :

```
painter->setBrush(QColor(122, 163, 39));
painter->drawPath(intersectedPath);
```

Comment: this solution partially works due to a lack of information in my description. I added new information in "Edit 1".

Comment: In this solution there is no need for a point. You can just retrieve the intersected area and paint it with some brush.

Comment: I use a starting point to call *Items()* method on it, retrieving the list of Items at that point. Then I can use your solution to calculate the overlapping area. But in the last case (in Edit 1 picture) calling `Items(QPoint p)` method, with 'p' anywhere in the red area, will return an empty list.  
Do you think I could use a QImage to simply draw some shapes?